# Ubuntu virtual terminals hotkey problem

Tags: video, intel-graphics, virtual-terminal

This problem appears from at least 11.04 till at least 12.04.

Usually if you want to open one of six virtual terminals, you press hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-6]</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to `X`).

But I have a problem on every build I've tested that virtual terminals which are opened with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-6]</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not used). So if you want just to close an application (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) or to open an "Execute" dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), you firstly get `#4` or `#2` virtual terminal and after that when you come back to `#7` (`X`), the requested action is executed.

The only solution for now I've found by experiment is restarting the `X` user session. So every time I boot in Ubuntu, I have to re-login to cure this bug till my next boot.

I've looked for solutions in the Internet, but my question formulations have been luring me to other problems, very far from mine.

Hardware info:

> ## dmidecode 2.11
>
> SMBIOS 2.6 present.
>   63 structures occupying 2519 bytes.
>   Table at 0x000E0850.
>
> Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
>   BIOS Information
>     Vendor: Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
>     Version: 05FI
>     Release Date: 10/12/2011
>     Address: 0xE0000
>     Runtime Size: 128 kB
>     ROM Size: 2560 kB
>     Characteristics:
>         PCI is supported
>         BIOS is upgradeable
>         BIOS shadowing is allowed
>         Boot from CD is supported
>         Selectable boot is supported
>         EDD is supported
>         Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
>         8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
>         Serial services are supported (int 14h)
>         Printer services are supported (int 17h)
>         CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
>         NEC PC-98
>         ACPI is supported
>         USB legacy is supported
>         BIOS boot specification is supported
>         Function key-initiated network boot is supported
>         Targeted content distribution is supported
>     BIOS Revision: 0.1
>
> Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
>   System Information
>     Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
>     Product Name: 300V3A/300V4A/300V5A/200A4B/200A5B
>     Version: 0.1
>     Serial Number: HN6B93QBC00323
>     UUID: 1FA57720-1DD2-11B2-8000-B933AB406D0D
>     Wake-up Type: Other
>     SKU Number: System SKUNumber
>     Family: HuronRiver System
>
> Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
>   Base Board Information
>     Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
>     Product Name: 300V3A/300V4A/300V5A/200A4B/200A5B
>     Version: FAB1
>     Serial Number: 123490EN400015
>     Asset Tag: Base Board Asset Tag
>     Features:
>         Board is a hosting board
>         Board is replaceable
>     Location In Chassis: Part Component
>     Chassis Handle: 0x0000
>     Type: Motherboard
>     Contained Object Handles: 0
>
> Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 21 bytes
>   Chassis Information
>     Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
>     Type: Laptop
>     Lock: Not Present
>     Version: 0.1
>     Serial Number: 123490EN400015
>     Asset Tag: Asset Tag
>     Boot-up State: Safe
>     Power Supply State: Safe
>     Thermal State: Other
>     Security Status: Other
>     OEM Information: 0x00000000
>     Height: Unspecified
>     Number Of Power Cords: 1
>     Contained Elements: 0
>
> Handle 0x0004, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: Keyboard
>     External Connector Type: PS/2
>     Port Type: Keyboard Port
>
> Handle 0x0005, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: Mouse
>     External Connector Type: PS/2
>     Port Type: Mouse Port
>
> Handle 0x0006, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: Other
>     External Reference Designator: COM 1
>     External Connector Type: None
>     Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible
>
> Handle 0x0007, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 1#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x0008, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 2#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 3#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 4#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 5#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 6#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 7#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 8#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 9#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 10#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 11#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 12#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 13#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: USB2.0 - 14#
>     External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
>     Port Type: USB
>
> Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: Ethernet
>     External Connector Type: RJ-45
>     Port Type: Network Port
>
> Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: SATA Port 1 J8J1
>     Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
>     External Reference Designator: None
>     External Connector Type: None
>     Port Type: SATA
>
> Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: SATA Port 2 J7G1
>     Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
>     External Reference Designator: None
>     External Connector Type: None
>     Port Type: SATA
>
> Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: SATA Port 3(ODD) J9E7
>     Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
>     External Reference Designator: None
>     External Connector Type: None
>     Port Type: SATA
>
> Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: eSATA Port 1 J6J1
>     External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
>     Port Type: SATA
>
> Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: eSATA Port 2 J7J1
>     External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
>     Port Type: SATA
>
> Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
>   Port Connector Information
>     Internal Reference Designator: None
>     Internal Connector Type: None
>     External Reference Designator: SATA Port 6(Docking)
>     External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
>     Port Type: SATA
>
> Handle 0x001C, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
>   System Slot Information
>     Designation: PEG Gen1/Gen2 X16
>     Type: x16 PCI Express x16
>     Current Usage: In Use
>     Length: Long
>     ID: 0
>     Characteristics:
>         3.3 V is provided
>         Opening is shared
>         PME signal is supported
>     Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0
>
> Handle 0x001D, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
>   System Slot Information
>     Designation: PCI-Express 1 X1
>     Type: x1 PCI Express
>     Current Usage: In Use
>     Length: Short
>     ID: 1
>     Characteristics:
>         3.3 V is provided
>         Opening is shared
>         PME signal is supported
>     Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0
>
> Handle 0x001E, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
>   System Slot Information
>     Designation: PCI-Express 2 X1
>     Type: x1 PCI Express
>     Current Usage: Available
>     Length: Short
>     ID: 2
>     Characteristics:
>         3.3 V is provided
>         Opening is shared
>         PME signal is supported
>     Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0
>
> Handle 0x001F, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
>   System Slot Information
>     Designation: PCI-Express 3 X1
>     Type: x1 PCI Express
>     Current Usage: Available
>     Length: Short
>     ID: 3
>     Characteristics:
>         3.3 V is provided
>         Opening is shared
>         PME signal is supported
>     Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0
>
> Handle 0x0020, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
>   System Slot Information
>     Designation: PCI-Express 4 X1
>     Type: x1 PCI Express
>     Current Usage: In Use
>     Length: Short
>     ID: 4
>     Characteristics:
>         3.3 V is provided
>         Opening is shared
>         PME signal is supported
>     Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0
>
> Handle 0x0021, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
>   System Slot Information
>     Designation: PCI-Express 5 X1
>     Type: x1 PCI Express
>     Current Usage: Available
>     Length: Short
>     ID: 5
>     Characteristics:
>         3.3 V is provided
>         Opening is shared
>         PME signal is supported
>     Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0
>
> Handle 0x0022, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
>   On Board Device Information
>     Type: Video
>     Status: Enabled
>     Description: Intel(R) Extreme Graphics 3 Controller
>
> Handle 0x0023, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
>   On Board Device Information
>     Type: Sound
>     Status: Enabled
>     Description: Intel(R) Azalia Audio Device
>
> Handle 0x0024, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
>   OEM Strings
>     String 1: AAABAAAAAAAA 
>     String 2: 2012/02/22
>
> Handle 0x0025, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
>   System Configuration Options
>
> Handle 0x0026, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
>   BIOS Language Information
>     Language Description Format: Abbreviated
>     Installable Languages: 4
>         en-US
>         fr-FR
>         ja-JP
>         ko-KR
>     Currently Installed Language: en-US
>
> Handle 0x0027, DMI type 22, 26 bytes
>   Portable Battery
>     Location: Rear
>     Manufacturer: Intel Corp.
>     Manufacture Date: 2008
>     Serial Number: 1.0
>     Name: Smart Battery
>     Design Capacity: Unknown
>     Design Voltage: Unknown
>     SBDS Version: V1.0
>     Maximum Error: Unknown
>     SBDS Chemistry: Lithium-Ion
>     OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
>
> Handle 0x0028, DMI type 32, 11 bytes
>   System Boot Information
>     Status: No errors detected
>
> Handle 0x0029, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
>   32-bit Memory Error Information
>     Type: OK
>     Granularity: Unknown
>     Operation: Unknown
>     Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
>     Memory Array Address: Unknown
>     Device Address: Unknown
>     Resolution: Unknown
>
> Handle 0x002A, DMI type 21, 7 bytes
>   Built-in Pointing Device
>     Type: Mouse
>     Interface: PS/2
>     Buttons: 2
>
> Handle 0x002B, DMI type 23, 13 bytes
>   System Reset
>     Status: Disabled
>     Watchdog Timer: Present
>     Boot Option: Do Not Reboot
>     Boot Option On Limit: Do Not Reboot
>     Reset Count: Unknown
>     Reset Limit: Unknown
>     Timer Interval: Unknown
>     Timeout: Unknown
>
> Handle 0x002C, DMI type 24, 5 bytes
>   Hardware Security
>     Power-On Password Status: Unknown
>     Keyboard Password Status: Unknown
>     Administrator Password Status: Unknown
>     Front Panel Reset Status: Unknown
>
> Handle 0x002D, DMI type 27, 14 bytes
>   Cooling Device
>     Type: Unknown
>     Status: Unknown
>     OEM-specific Information: 0x00000090
>     Nominal Speed: Unknown Or Non-rotating
>
> Handle 0x002E, DMI type 39, 22 bytes
>   System Power Supply
>     Location: TBD by ODM
>     Name: TBD by ODM
>     Manufacturer: TBD by ODM
>     Serial Number: TBD by ODM
>     Asset Tag: TBD by ODM
>     Model Part Number: TBD by ODM
>     Revision: 1.0
>     Max Power Capacity: Unknown
>     Status: Present, OK
>     Type: Battery
>     Input Voltage Range Switching: Other
>     Plugged: Yes
>     Hot Replaceable: Yes
>
> Handle 0x002F, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
>   Processor Information
>     Socket Designation: CPU
>     Type: Central Processor
>     Family: Core i7
>     Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
>     ID: A7 06 02 00 FF FB EB BF
>     Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 42, Stepping 7
>     Flags:
>         FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
>         VME (Virtual mode extension)
>         DE (Debugging extension)
>         PSE (Page size extension)
>         TSC (Time stamp counter)
>         MSR (Model specific registers)
>         PAE (Physical address extension)
>         MCE (Machine check exception)
>         CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
>         APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
>         SEP (Fast system call)
>         MTRR (Memory type range registers)
>         PGE (Page global enable)
>         MCA (Machine check architecture)
>         CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
>         PAT (Page attribute table)
>         PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
>         CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
>         DS (Debug store)
>         ACPI (ACPI supported)
>         MMX (MMX technology supported)
>         FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
>         SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
>         SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
>         SS (Self-snoop)
>         HTT (Multi-threading)
>         TM (Thermal monitor supported)
>         PBE (Pending break enabled)
>     Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
>     Voltage: 1.2 V
>     External Clock: 100 MHz
>     Max Speed: 2500 MHz
>     Current Speed: 2500 MHz
>     Status: Populated, Enabled
>     Upgrade: ZIF Socket
>     L1 Cache Handle: 0x0030
>     L2 Cache Handle: 0x0031
>     L3 Cache Handle: 0x0032
>     Serial Number: Not Supported by CPU
>     Asset Tag: TBD By OEM
>     Part Number: TBD By OEM
>     Core Count: 2
>     Core Enabled: 2
>     Thread Count: 4
>     Characteristics:
>         64-bit capable
>
> Handle 0x0030, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
>   Cache Information
>     Socket Designation: L1-Cache
>     Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
>     Operational Mode: Write Through
>     Location: Internal
>     Installed Size: 64 kB
>     Maximum Size: 64 kB
>     Supported SRAM Types:
>         Synchronous
>     Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
>     Speed: Unknown
>     Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
>     System Type: Data
>     Associativity: 8-way Set-associative
>
> Handle 0x0031, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
>   Cache Information
>     Socket Designation: L2-Cache
>     Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
>     Operational Mode: Write Through
>     Location: Internal
>     Installed Size: 256 kB
>     Maximum Size: 256 kB
>     Supported SRAM Types:
>         Synchronous
>     Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
>     Speed: Unknown
>     Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
>     System Type: Data
>     Associativity: 8-way Set-associative
>
> Handle 0x0032, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
>   Cache Information
>     Socket Designation: L3-Cache
>     Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
>     Operational Mode: Write Back
>     Location: Internal
>     Installed Size: 3072 kB
>     Maximum Size: 3072 kB
>     Supported SRAM Types:
>         Synchronous
>     Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
>     Speed: Unknown
>     Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
>     System Type: Unified
>     Associativity: 12-way Set-associative
>
> Handle 0x0033, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
>   Physical Memory Array
>     Location: System Board Or Motherboard
>     Use: System Memory
>     Error Correction Type: None
>     Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
>     Error Information Handle: Not Provided
>     Number Of Devices: 4
>
> Handle 0x0034, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
>   Memory Device
>     Array Handle: 0x0033
>     Error Information Handle: Not Provided
>     Total Width: 64 bits
>     Data Width: 64 bits
>     Size: 2048 MB
>     Form Factor: SODIMM
>     Set: None
>     Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
>     Bank Locator: BANK 0
>     Type: DDR3
>     Type Detail: Synchronous
>     Speed: 1333 MHz
>     Manufacturer: Samsung
>     Serial Number: B41CC40D
>     Asset Tag: 9876543210
>     Part Number: M471B5773CHS-CH9
>     Rank: Unknown
>
> Handle 0x0035, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
>   Memory Device Mapped Address
>     Starting Address: 0x00000000000
>     Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
>     Range Size: 2 GB
>     Physical Device Handle: 0x0034
>     Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x003A
>     Partition Row Position: Unknown
>     Interleave Position: 1
>     Interleaved Data Depth: 2
>
> Handle 0x0036, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
>   Memory Device
>     Array Handle: 0x0033
>     Error Information Handle: Not Provided
>     Total Width: Unknown
>     Data Width: Unknown
>     Size: No Module Installed
>     Form Factor: DIMM
>     Set: None
>     Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
>     Bank Locator: BANK 1
>     Type: Unknown
>     Type Detail: None
>     Speed: Unknown
>     Manufacturer: Not Specified
>     Serial Number: Not Specified
>     Asset Tag: 9876543210
>     Part Number: Not Specified
>     Rank: Unknown
>
> Handle 0x0037, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
>   Memory Device
>     Array Handle: 0x0033
>     Error Information Handle: Not Provided
>     Total Width: 64 bits
>     Data Width: 64 bits
>     Size: 4096 MB
>     Form Factor: SODIMM
>     Set: None
>     Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
>     Bank Locator: BANK 2
>     Type: DDR3
>     Type Detail: Synchronous
>     Speed: 1333 MHz
>     Manufacturer: Samsung
>     Serial Number: 01190CD6
>     Asset Tag: 9876543210
>     Part Number: M471B5273CM0-CH9
>     Rank: Unknown
>
> Handle 0x0038, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
>   Memory Device Mapped Address
>     Starting Address: 0x00080000000
>     Ending Address: 0x0017FFFFFFF
>     Range Size: 4 GB
>     Physical Device Handle: 0x0037
>     Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x003A
>     Partition Row Position: Unknown
>     Interleave Position: 2
>     Interleaved Data Depth: 2
>
> Handle 0x0039, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
>   Memory Device
>     Array Handle: 0x0033
>     Error Information Handle: Not Provided
>     Total Width: Unknown
>     Data Width: Unknown
>     Size: No Module Installed
>     Form Factor: DIMM
>     Set: None
>     Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
>     Bank Locator: BANK 3
>     Type: Unknown
>     Type Detail: None
>     Speed: Unknown
>     Manufacturer: Not Specified
>     Serial Number: Not Specified
>     Asset Tag: 9876543210
>     Part Number: Not Specified
>     Rank: Unknown
>
> Handle 0x003A, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
>   Memory Array Mapped Address
>     Starting Address: 0x00000000000
>     Ending Address: 0x0017FFFFFFF
>     Range Size: 6 GB
>     Physical Array Handle: 0x0033
>     Partition Width: 4
>
> Handle 0x003B, DMI type 129, 8 bytes
>   OEM-specific Type
>     Header and Data:
>         81 08 3B 00 01 01 02 01
>     Strings:
>         Intel_ASF
>         Intel_ASF_001
>
> Handle 0x003C, DMI type 131, 64 bytes
>   OEM-specific Type
>     Header and Data:
>         83 40 3C 00 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>         F8 00 49 1C FF FF FF FF 09 C0 00 00 01 00 07 00
>         40 04 0D 00 00 00 00 00 C8 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00
>         00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 76 50 72 6F 00 00 00 00
>
> Handle 0x003D, DMI type 15, 29 bytes
>   System Event Log
>     Area Length: 18 bytes
>     Header Start Offset: 0x0000
>     Header Length: 16 bytes
>     Data Start Offset: 0x0010
>     Access Method: General-purpose non-volatile data functions
>     Access Address: 0x00F0
>     Status: Valid, Not Full
>     Change Token: 0x00000000
>     Header Format: Type 1
>     Supported Log Type Descriptors: 3
>     Descriptor 1: POST error
>     Data Format 1: POST results bitmap
>     Descriptor 2: Single-bit ECC memory error
>     Data Format 2: Multiple-event
>     Descriptor 3: Multi-bit ECC memory error
>     Data Format 3: Multiple-event
>
> Handle 0x003E, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
>   End Of Table

Comment: Alt-Fn by itself switches the tty when you are not in an X session. Based on googling, it sounds like you have a problem with either the video driver starting correctly or with the keyboard itself not being detected properly during start up - and restarting the X session causes whatever the problem is to load correctly. Are you able to try booting with a different keyboard plugged in?

Comment: I've already tested another keyboard, another video card (but the same "family" - Intel) and another pc (my current pc is notebook, my last - stationary).
Maybe there is an extra, correct driver pack for integrated intel video?

Comment: So, for the many years onli me have this problem, right? And no solution?

Comment: Something in your boot configuration is preventing X from starting correctly or at least from properly handling key events. Restarting X fixes it. Have you always upgraded in place or have you tried a fresh install of 12.04 or 12.10?

Comment: I always make a fresh install, not update.

Comment: I've installed fresh video drivers from Intel own repository.
Not a solution.

Comment: Hardware info is added. Thank you, chaskes, for trying to help!

Comment: Could you include the contents of your lightdm.log? (Or whatever DM you are using?)

Comment: Also, please indicate more of your install details, Unity, KDE, etc, and what keyboard layout are you using.

Comment: My /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log is empty.

Comment: The OS details are: Ubuntu 11.04 (Gnome 2), Ubuntu 12.04 (gnome-fallback) with lightdm.
Keyboard layouts: EN (def. english), RU (russian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a real solution!

The problem appears in several versions of Ubuntu (at least, 12.04 which I'm using now). Well I can't explain everything in details, but the problem is the "FRAMEBUFFER" option which is missed in the initramfs settings.

The solution is:

```
sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
# append "FRAMEBUFFER=Y" to the end of this file
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
# reboot your OS or type "setupcon" in the terminal
...
PROFIT!
```

Also this solution resolves the problem when cyrillic symbols aren't shown in the terminal but the squares are shown.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of people out there talking about similar problems, but after a lot of Googling and learning more about X11 keyboard events and keyboard configurations, I think the problem is a combination of your hardware and the Russian keyboard.

Using `xev` to see key events, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as (shortened output):

```
KeyPress event keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event keycode 67 (keysym 0x1008fe01, XF86Switch_VT_1), same_screen YES
```

Note that keycode 67 (F1) -- when preceded by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> -- is *not* mapped to the keysym `F1` but to a keysym called`XF86XK_Switch_VT_1`, which is defined in X11 as (decimal) 67.

In other words, your problem can be re-stated as: X doesn't see `67 (F1)` after `ctrl-alt` as `XF86XK_Switch_VT_1` until I logout and log back in.

At that point, I figured the solution should be to create an `~/.Xmodmap` file to force the mapping on startup. You only need one line:

```
keycode 67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
```

The exact syntax was difficult, but now knowing to search for `XF86XK_Switch_VT_1`, I found two pages with the same problem (one mentioning an Italian keyboard) and both gave the syntax as above. ([here](http://lswest-ubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/03/xorg-tty-switching-is-wrong.html) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34460/disabling-or-changing-console-switching-keys)).

I'm reasonably confident this will solve your problem. You may need to add similar lines for F2-6.

---

Here's what I think is happening:

For whatever reason, when X first starts, it is not able to correctly load the default keymap (usually `/etc/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`) where 67 is mapped to `<FK01>`. Keymapping errors do not cause X to fail, so you are able to log in. But the X way of switching to tty fails, allowing the key event to fall through to the non-X way switching method. When you re-login, again for whatever reason, X correctly loads the keymapping.

Why the one and not the other? I don't know, but I can guess it's related either to user settings for the keyboard layout, other mapping changes that may have caused conflicts, hardware (67 is not standard for F1 across manufacturers but 67 is defined for `XF86Switch_VT_1` in [XF86keysym.h](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/tree/XF86keysym.h), so if it doesn't get mapped correctly, switching won't work), or a combination of the two.

Comment: Thank you for lurking, **chaskes**.
Unfortunately your solution hasn't worked for me.

1. `xmodmap -pke` shows me the settings for keycode 67:
>  keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
The same settings are after X-restart. So nothing changes after logout/login.

2. Anyway I've tried to create an ~/.Xmodmap file and to use it for modifying my keys mapping via `xmodmap .Xmodmap` command. After that the settings for keycode 67 were altered, of course:
> keycode 67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
But it didn't solve the problem anyway.

Comment: I'll keep thinking about it, but I don't know if I'll have any other suggestions.